# How to use UIScrollview scroll to page when touch button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want a UIScrollView that works like:

when I tap button "page1" scrollview will scroll to page 1

when I tap button "page2" scrollview will scroll to page 2

Any help thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose the height value of your one page is `pageHeight`,

```
CGPoint contentOffset = yourScroll.contentOffset
contentOffset.y = pageHeight * pageIndex;
[yourScroll setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
```

hope this helpful

Comment: It works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = yourScrollView;

CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
NSInteger pageNumber = xxx;//Whatever page you want to go

//If your scroll is horizonal
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageNumber;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

//If your scroll is vertical
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = frame.size.height * pageNumber;;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```